# get the dynamically created multiple select box values using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have been reviewing a lot of pages about this and can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

And I have a doubt in the section of,if i have multiple dynamically created select box and this selected values to be passed to the text box with some calculation before using jQuery. please help me i have tortured in this section.
In the below line of input.php have the html code of get the input.

```
    function addMore() {
        $("<DIV>").load("input.php", function() {
                $("#product").append($(this).html());


        });

    }
    function deleteRow() {
        $('DIV.product-item').each(function(index, item){
            jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(item).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.product-item').change(function()
           {

                var option1 =$(this).find('.orderbox1 option:selected').val();
                var option2 = $(this).find('.orderbox2 option:selected').val();
                option1 *= $(".orderbox3").val();
                option2 *= $(".orderbox3").val();
                $(".orderbox4").val(option1-option2);

        });
    }); 

    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <FORM name="frmProduct" method="post" action="">
    <DIV id="outer">
    <DIV id="header">
    <DIV class="float-left" style="margin-left:150px;">&nbsp;</DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left col-heading">Choose Currency</DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left col-heading">Choose Product</DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left col-heading">Forex Amount</DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left col-heading">Rupee Amount</DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV id="product">

<DIV class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;">
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"> Choose Currency:
           <select  name="item_currency[]" id="orderbox1" class="orderbox1" style="width:150px;">
            <option selected="selected">Select</option> 
             <option value="66">United States</option>
            <option value="75">European</option>
            <option value="12">Philippines</option>
            <option value="17">Qatar</option>

        </select></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"> Choose Product:
                <select name="item_size[]" id="orderbox2" class="orderbox2">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="10">Forex Card</option>
                <option value="20">Currency Notes</option>
                </select></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="orderbox3" class="orderbox3"/></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="orderbox4" class="orderbox4"/></DIV>
</DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="btn-action float-clear">
    <input type="button" name="add_item" value="Add More" onClick="addMore();" />
    <input type="button" name="del_item" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow();" />F
    <span class="success"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; }?></span>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="footer">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
    </DIV>
    </DIV>
    </FORM>
```

Comment: please anyone help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like you are trying to attach a `change` handler to a `div`.  This is not possible.  From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/) -

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

To get it to work you can change this -

```
$('.product-item').change(function() {
```

to -

```
$('.product-item select, .product-item input').change(function() {
```

Secondly, to handle dynamic rows you you  need to use event delegation.  Using [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) you can apply the function to dynamic elements.  You will need to change the function to -

```js
$("#product").on('change', '.product-item select, .product-item input', function() {
  var $line = $(this).parents('.product-item');
  var option1 = $line.find('.orderbox1').val();
  var option2 = $line.find('.orderbox2').val();
  option1 *= $line.find(".orderbox3").val();
  option2 *= $line.find(".orderbox3").val();
  $line.find(".orderbox4").val(option1 - option2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV id="product">
  <DIV class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;">
    <DIV class="float-left">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" />
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">Choose Currency:
      <select name="item_currency[]" id="orderbox1" class="orderbox1" style="width:150px;">
        <option selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="66">United States</option>
        <option value="75">European</option>
        <option value="12">Philippines</option>
        <option value="17">Qatar</option>

      </select>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">Choose Product:
      <select name="item_size[]" id="orderbox2" class="orderbox2">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="10">Forex Card</option>
        <option value="20">Currency Notes</option>
      </select>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">
      <input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="orderbox3" class="orderbox3" />
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">
      <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="orderbox4" class="orderbox4" />
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;">
    <DIV class="float-left">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" />
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">Choose Currency:
      <select name="item_currency[]" id="orderbox1" class="orderbox1" style="width:150px;">
        <option selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="66">United States</option>
        <option value="75">European</option>
        <option value="12">Philippines</option>
        <option value="17">Qatar</option>

      </select>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">Choose Product:
      <select name="item_size[]" id="orderbox2" class="orderbox2">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="10">Forex Card</option>
        <option value="20">Currency Notes</option>
      </select>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">
      <input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="orderbox3" class="orderbox3" />
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="float-left">
      <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="orderbox4" class="orderbox4" />
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

Here I'm creating a variable (`$line`) to represent the row. I can then use find to get the `orderbox`es for that row.

Comment: ya great man..its working thanks for everything..you done a great job..@john

Comment: @navaskhan Not a problem, event delegation catches everyone out at some point.

Comment: @navaskhan Codeschool (https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery) seem to have some pretty decent free courses for the beginner though I find looking through answers on here can reveal some real gems, especially the well explained ones.

Comment: I have also one question just like the previous one..i provide this example jsfiddle.net/wktLxugh/ it works..but not work on dynamic creation.

Comment: That's basically the same thing, the `.on` statement should be applied to a static parent element. So you want your first line to look something like `$(**parentObjectSelector**).on(**event**, **selectorForElementsWhereTheEventHappens**, **handlerFunction**);`.

Comment: Its not Working..the below code                                                                         $(".product-item").on('change', 'select',function(){
 var select = $('#orderbox2');
    select.empty();
    $.each(categories[$(':selected', this).text()], function(){
        select.append('<option value="'+this.value+'">'+this.text+'</option>');
    });
});

Comment: if you are in line please help me..this is at final stage of project...the above line is working but not an dynamic creation.

Comment: Assuming your dynamic content is a new instance of `.product-item` you need to add the `.on` statement to the element you are appending it to (I'm assuming `#product` based on your original question).  I've added some code to your fiddle to add dynamic content and updated your `selectChange` function accordingly - http://jsfiddle.net/wktLxugh/1/

Comment: little bit issues in this code.please have to clear this sir,I am struggling with that,when clicking outside of the forex amount textbox it change the values in the last checkbox please have to help me..avoid of changing outside click.

Comment: sir please help to avoid when click outside of changing values.My idea have change automatically while enter of third box values to fourth box..

Comment: Please create a new question with your current code and explaining your problem.

Comment: I had my questions please be need have to clear that.